# Grails Fullcalendar Timezone Issue

Tags: grails, fullcalendar

I am sitting on a really strange issue with grails and the js fullcalendar.

I have users which have their own timezones stored in the database e.g. ECT

When users insert their events all dates are stored in UTC. This is set in the Bootstrap with:

```
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
```

I heard its a good idea to store all dates in UTC. So when a german user is entering 1.12.2012 08:00 its stored with 1.12.2012 07:00. This is fine.

Now when I want to display those values from the db into the calendar the timezone is not considered by fullcalendar(i set ignoreTimezone: false) so the dates are comming over json with 2012-12-01 08:00+01:00 but its display as 08:00 am and not 07:00. What am I doing wrong here? this issue is driving me really crazy.

Comment: can you check on this post and see if this helps..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724142/fullcalendar-and-timezones-help-im-doing-it-wrong.

Comment: I already checked this post but in my case full calendar is not displaying the right values. Question, if I pass the value 2012-12-01 08:00+01:00 to full calendar what time should be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check in by manually adding the event in javascript?I guess the problem is with the JSON format. The parseISO8601 function inside fullcalendar.js expects your object to be in some format and so if your format is not correct,then you have to experiment and see what works.

Quoted from fullcalendar website.

> When specifying Event Objects for events or eventSources, you may
>   specify a string in IETF format (ex: "Wed, 18 Oct 2009 13:00:00 EST"),
>   a string in ISO8601 format (ex: "2009-11-05T13:15:30Z") or a UNIX
>   timestamp.